# Hashmap inserting first record in 12th index

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I'm inserting a ArrayList into map (Object id as key and object as value).

First insertion is happening at 12th index.

Since default size is 16 for HashMap, It is inserting 4th record in first index.(Since index reached last means 16th).

So I'm getting wrong order.

Even I tried with `LinkedHashMap`. Same result is coming.

And here is my code:

```
for (Type object: Objects) {
      map.put(object.obj.getId() , object);
    }
```

Please Help me to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: What order are you expecting? HashMap has no ordering? LinkedHashMap gives you insertion order. If you want the keys ordered, use TreeMap.

Comment: @Eran I'm inserting 6 records in a Map. Insertion is starting from 12th index. (I saw by debugging it.) But I want it from 1st .

Comment: You don't control the index (at least not directly). The index is determined based on the `hashCode`. And you shouldn't care about the index anyway.

Comment: Then How can I get the first inserted record in beginning of the map. I need to have a insertion order. I tried LinkedHashMap also. It is also giving same result (Starting from 12th)

Comment: Your first record is still in the original List. If you want to keep track of the order in which you inserted the objects, you can store the ids in another List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maps are not intended for index based access. There is nothing like `map.get(index)`. All that is possible is preserved order while iterating as described in other answers/comments:

```
for (Type object: Objects) {
    map.put(object.obj.getId() , object);
}
for (Entry entry: map.entrySet()) {
    // should be same order as inserted if LinkedHashMap is used
}
```

You should not care about that internal state of the Map. All that counts is the described behaviour of the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Comment: But here insertion itself a problem. Last record is inserting in beginning.

Comment: @SivaPasupathi no, the internal data of the LinkedHashMap stores it at some index in the hastable. That does not mean that it behaves like this. Stop debugging into libraries and start reading API documentation. If you try out my example, it'll work exactly as described. The element that you see stored at 12th index, will turn up first upon iteration.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedHashMap is precisely what you're looking for.

It is exactly like HashMap, except that when you iterate over it, it presents the items in the insertion order.